# how to show embed base64 image in prettyPhoto

Tags: javascript, html, base64, prettyphoto

I want to use a plugin like `prettyPhoto` to show images for one of my site(rel attribute).

I embedded  images directly in HTML documents using  `Base64` `image embedding technique`. 
**Example**

```
<a href="http://www.britblog.com/">
    <img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhUAAPAKIAAAsLav///88PD9WqsYmApmZmZtZfYmdakyH5BAQUAP8ALAAAAABQAA8AAAPb
    WLrc/jDKSVe4OOvNu/9gqARDSRBHegyGMahqO4R0bQcjIQ8E4BMCQc930JluyGRmdAAcdiigMLVr
    ApTYWy5FKM1IQe+Mp+L4rphz+qIOBAUYeCY4p2tGrJZeH9y79mZsawFoaIRxF3JyiYxuHiMGb5KT
    kpFvZj4ZbYeCiXaOiKBwnxh4fnt9e3ktgZyHhrChinONs3cFAShFF2JhvCZlG5uchYNun5eedRxM
    AF15XEFRXgZWWdciuM8GCmdSQ84lLQfY5R14wDB5Lyon4ubwS7jx9NcV9/j5+g4JADs="
    alt="British Blog Directory" width="80" height="15" />
</a>
```

My question is how can I achieve it using prettyPhoto or are there any java-script plugin  which supports my requirement?

Comment: I dont think the rules of SO allow you to ask for a plugin. What have you tried? this is just an img tag. where is the code?

Comment: hi have converted image to  64base string, it means no external image file when using an <img> element in HTML,
This link shows how I achieved it 
http://css-tricks.com/data-uris/